# WPF datagrid selection to another usercontrol

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying to take the information from a datagrid selection, press a button and display all the details in a new user control. I am struggling to work out how to bind the selected item and bring it across to a new window or user control.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the MVVM pattern you can use the same viewmodel for multiple views.  So in this case changing the selected item in one view would cause an update to a property in its viewmodel.  That viewmodel is then also used by a second (or third, or fourth) view, and will receive the update accordingly.